# Is memset(&mystruct, 0, sizeof mystruct) same as mystruct = { 0 };?

Tags: c, struct

I'm reading about the initialized values by default  of an array/struct and have this question:

is `memset(&mystruct, 0, sizeof mystruct)` same as `mystruct = { 0 };` ?

if it's not, what's difference?

Comment: @awoodland: Do you? Then which was the `sizeof` variant that doesn't need the parens?

Comment: @awoodland: `sizeof` in C, is an operator not a function. The `()` is optional. See `memset(&f, 0, sizeof f);` it works fine for me.

Comment: People, look up what the definition of `sizeof` is. It is an unary operator which operates either on a variable or on a **cast expression**. As you should know, a cast expression is a type within parentheses. Therefore `sizeof` itself doesn't 'need' parenthesis, it's the cast expression that requires it.

Comment: Right, my point was to underline that the parenthesis is not part of `sizeof` but on the 'object' it operates on. The same with `return`which annoys me a lot when people put systematically parenthesis, as if it was a function.

Comment: @tristopia Ok, I'll buy that - sorry for taking this on a tangent.

Comment: No, you were right to actually reference the standard, my comment was indeed a little bit sloppy.

Comment: Why the first comment was removed? the comments now seems a bit no sense.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> is memset(&mystruct, 0, sizeof mystruct) same as mystruct = { 0 }; ?

No.

```
memset(&mystruct, 0, sizeof mystruct) ;
```

... will tell the compiler to call a function that we expect will set **during execution** the data in mystruct to zero.

```
mystruct = { 0 };
```

... will set tell the compiler set by itself the data to zero, which means it will:

- *if possible*, set the data in mystruct to zero **at compilation** (e.g. for static variables, as [tristopia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/146377/tristopia) and [Oli Charlesworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129570/oli-charlesworth) remarked in the comments)
- or *if not* (e.g. auto variables), to generate the assembly code that will set the data to zero when the variable is initialized (which is better than calling a function to do that).

Note that *perhaps* the compiler could optimize the memset into a compile-time instruction (*like replacing the first version with the second version*), but I wouldn't rely on that as `memset` is a function from the runtime library, not some language intrinsic (*I'm not a compiler writer/language lawyer, though*).

Coming from C++, my own viewpoint is that the more you can do at compilation and the more the compiler knows at compile time, before the execution even starts, the better: It enables the compiler to possibly optimize the code and/or generate warning/errors.

In the current case, using the `mystruct = { 0 };` notation to initialize a `struct` is always safer than using the memset because it is very *very* easy write the wrong thing in C with a `memset` without the compiler complaining.

The following examples show that it is easy for the code to do something different than it appears to do:

```
// only the 1st byte will be set to 0
memset(&mystruct, 0, sizeof(char)) ;          

// will probably overrun the data, possibly corrupting
// the data around it, and you hope, crashing the process.
memset(&mystruct, 0, sizeof(myLARGEstruct)) ; 

// will NOT set the data to 257. Instead it will truncate the
// integer and set each byte to 1
memset(&mystruct, 257, sizeof(mystruct)) ;    

// will set each byte to the value of sizeof(mystruct) modulo 256
memset(&mystruct, sizeof(mystruct), 0) ;      

// will work. Always.
mystruct = { 0 } ;
```

Comment: Not true if mystruct is an auto variable. In that case both are runtime initialisations and it will happen on every call to the function it is declared in.

Comment: Try `typedef struct A { int v ; } A ; void setZero(void) { A a = {0} ; }` instead. An auto variable is a local variable, it has nothing to do with pointers.

Comment: @tristopia : You're right. I mis-read your comment, and removed my previous comments when I realized it. Anyway, even not mentioning the unsafety-ness of memset, I do believe the initialization of a struct with `= {0} ;` can produce better results than memsetting it to zero (looking at the disassembly in gcc confirms it, as memset involves a function call).

Comment: So, both cases I have same side effect in my struct. Only with difference to when it will be set it. But there is a significative performance difference on set it during executation time instead of compilation or vice-versa?

Comment: Not even static objects are necessarily set during compilation. Quite often they are initialized before main() is called. When and where they are initialized is implementation-defined.

Comment: @Jack: Probably not. . . With `= {0} ;` the code is **safer**, and only *perhaps* faster. But if you have performance issues, as usual, profile *then* optimize the bottlenecks.

Comment: Won't the fourth example (`memset(..,..,0)`) not do _anything_ since the size parameter is zero?

Comment: It may be worth noting that the data representing '{0}' may be stored in _code_, depending on the compiler; this means for a large structure of POD types, you may be bloating code space with a large block of zeros, which may make a difference in a code-space limited applications like embedded environments (I've seen some sloppy, large structures (separate issue) allocated this way), but given the issues you mention in your answer, caution must clearly be exercised in making that determination.

Comment: `mystruct = { 0 } ;` is a syntax error, since `{ 0 }` is not an expression.

Comment: This answer at best makes a distinction that is not useful at best and not actually correct at worst. Modern compilers essentially treat struct initialization and `memset` equivalently and will usually either generate a handful of zeroing instructions if the aggregate is small (think a couple of `xors` or `movups`, depending on size) or a call to `memset` when this is not feasible in both cases. In particular, note that compile-time initialization is not a useful concept in this case. Also, `{}` is equivalent to `{ 0 }`.

Answer (score 11):

This is a completely pedantic answer, but given that the internal representation of a null pointer is not guaranted to be `0` the behavior of `memset` versus brace-initialization would differ (`memset` would do the wrong thing). That said, I've never heard of an implementation that took on this liberty to have a non all 0 bit pattern for null.

Comment: I've heard that on some embedded devices, that actually is the case. Never met one of those, though.

Comment: In the specific case the OP posted, there are no pointers to initialize.

Comment: @Lundin: How would you know that? There is no declaration for `mystruct` present.

Comment: what about floating point? Even if memsetting a double to zero would give zero (but what about signed zeros?), I would prefer the `={ 0 }` considering it a logical (rather than binary) initialization.

Comment: @ShinTakezou: Of course one would use brace-initialization to do initialization, and `memset` to fiddle with low level memory bit-patterns.

Answer (score 10):

```
memset(&mystruct, 0, sizeof mystruct);
```

is a statement. It can be executed any time where `mystruct` is visible, not just at the point where it's defined.

```
mystruct = { 0 };
```

is actually a syntax error; `{ 0 }` is not a valid expression.

(I'll assume that `mystruct` is an object of type `struct foo`.)

What you're probably thinking of is:

```
struct foo mystruct = { 0 };
```

where `{ 0 }` is an initializer.

If your compiler supports it, you can also write:

```
mystruct = (struct foo){ 0 };
```

where `(struct foo){ 0 }` is a *compound literal*.  Compound literals were introduced in C99; some C compilers, particularly Microsoft's probably don't support it.  (Note that the `(struct foo)` is *not* a cast operator; it looks similar to one, but it's not followed by an expression or parenthesized type name.  It's a distinct syntactic construct.)

If your compiler doesn't support compound literals, you can work around it by declaring a constant:

```
const struct foo foo_zero = { 0 };

struct foo mystruct;
/* ... */
mystruct = foo_zero;
```

So that's how they differ in syntax and in where you can use them.  There are also semantic differences.

The `memset` call sets all the bytes that make up the representation of `mystruct` to all zeros.  It's a very low-level operation.

On the other hand, the initializer:

```
struct foo mystruct = { 0 };
```

sets the *first* scalar subcomponent of `mystruct` to 0, and sets all other subcomponents as if they were initialized as static objects -- i.e., to 0.  (It would be nice if there were a cleaner `struct foo mystruct = { };` syntax to do the same thing, but there isn't.)

The thing is, setting something to `0` isn't necessarily the same thing as setting its representation to all-bits-zero.  The value `0` is *converted* to the appropriate type for each scalar subcomponent.

For integers, the language guarantees that all-bits-zero is a representation of `0` (but not necessarily the only representation of `0`).  It's very likely that setting an integer to `0` will set it to all-bits-zero, but it's conceivable that it could set it to some other representation of `0`.  In practice, that would only happen with a deliberately perverse compiler.

For pointers, *most* implementations represent null pointers as all-bits-zero, but the language doesn't guarantee that, and there have been real-world implementations that use some other representation. (For example, using something like all-bits-one might make null pointer dereferences easier to detect at run time.) And the representation may differ for different pointer types. See section 5 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/).

Similarly, for floating-point types, most implementations represent `0.0` as all-bits-zero, but the language standard doesn't guarantee it.

You can probably get away with writing code that *assumes* the `memset` call will set all subcomponents to zero, but such code is not strictly portable -- and [Murphy's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law) implies that the assumption will fail at the most inconvenient possible moment, perhaps when you port the code to an important new system.

Answer (score 9):

Theoretically there's a difference. The initialiser is not required to initialise the padding if there is some in `mystruct`. 
For example:

```
int main(void) 
{
     struct mystruct {
          char    a;
          int     what;
     } s = {0};
}
```

Might contain:

```
00 xx yy zz 00 00 00 00
```

where xx yy and zz are undefined bytes that where on the stack. 
The compiler is allowed to do that. 
This said, in all practical terms, I haven't encountered a compiler that did that yet. Most sane implementations will semantically handle that case like the  `memset`.

Comment: By 6.7.9(10) (in n1570), from C11 on, the padding must be set to zero-bits: "if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;", ditto for unions.

Comment: Since it wasn't in C99, I dare say it wasn't in C90.

Comment: You might consider adding the remark that it changed with C11, but I don't see much danger of the comment being deleted, so it's not necessary.

Comment: Interesting that would change in C11.  Does C11 impose other requirements on padding bits?  For example, if one has `struct {uint8_t b; uint32_t i;} s` and one says `s.b++;` on a machine where byte stores are slower than word stores, could the machine perform a word increment if, whenever it reads `b`, it masks the value with `0xFF` (so the value of the padding bits was never exposed except when overlaying the structure with `uint8[]`?)