# Why does removing println! cause a Windows API function called through FFI to fail?

Tags: rust, winmm

If I remove the `println!` from the following code, `waveOutPrepareHeader` returns code `MMSYSERR_INVALPARAM`.

```
fn write_audio_block(device: &PlaybackDevice, block: &[u8]) {
    use std::mem;
    use std::{thread, time};
    let mut header: mmsystem::WAVEHDR = unsafe { mem::uninitialized() };
    header.dwBufferLength = block.len() as winapi::minwindef::DWORD;
    header.lpData = block.as_ptr() as winapi::winnt::LPSTR;

    println!("ptr: {:?}\nlength: {:?}", // removing this causes error
         header.lpData,
         header.dwBufferLength);

    let header_size: winapi::minwindef::UINT = mem::size_of::<mmsystem::WAVEHDR>() as u32 +
                                           header.dwBufferLength as u32;

    catch_errors(unsafe { winmm::waveOutPrepareHeader(device.handle, &mut header, header_size) });

    catch_errors(unsafe { winmm::waveOutWrite(device.handle, &mut header, header_size) });

    thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(100));

    while unsafe { winmm::waveOutUnprepareHeader(device.handle, &mut header, header_size) } ==
        mmsystem::WAVERR_STILLPLAYING {
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(10));
    }
}
```

Even adding another `println!` or removing the `thread::sleep` after `waveOutWrite` will cause `waveOutPrepareHeader` to return `MMSYSERR_INVALPARAM`.

Otherwise it works fine.

Comment: Why is `block` a `&[u8]`? If you are modifying it, it *needs to be mutable*. If you are going to be writing unsafe code, you need to understand what restrictions you have to uphold. Having an immutable reference and a mutable reference is a sure-fire way to mess things up.

Comment: where am i modifying block?

Comment: Welcome to Undefined Behavior; now you understand why Rust being safe 99% of the time is so great! And... we probably won't be able to really help you, unfortunately, without a reproducible example. You may either reduce your problem as a [MCVE] so that we can assist OR use `valgrind` OR try out the [sanitizers](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/howto-sanitize-your-rust-code/9378) OR use a debugger.

Comment: Aren't you writing the audio data *into the slice* provided by the caller, modifying the data held within block? Isn't that why you get the pointer with `block.as_ptr()`, store in in your header struct, then pass the header struct to `waveOutWrite` and friends?

Comment: @MatthieuM. using Valgrind for a Windows FFI problem would be very useful, but I was under the impression that it didn't exist on Windows...?

Comment: @Shepmaster: Maybe with Windows 10? (I don't know how the new Bash on Windows works exactly). I expect there are equivalent to valgrind? Not quite sure if the sanitizers were ever made to work for Windows unfortunately.

Comment: Why are you *adding* the size of the allocated buffer to the size of the header? That's not the length of the header...

Comment: [`WAVEHDR` has **8** fields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743837(v=vs.85).aspx), of which you are only setting **2**. All the others are random junk memory. Instead of `mem::uninitialized` (which is documented as "This is incredibly dangerous and should not be done lightly"), try setting *all* the values to some reasonable initial value. My bet is that `println` just happens to clear some memory that the uninitialized variable is using.

Comment: Indeed, in C (where `uninitialized` is the default) you'd usually memset-0 a structure to make sure it doesn't have the random stuff left. cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788861/is-memsetmystruct-0-sizeof-mystruct-same-as-mystruct-0; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891720/initialize-reset-struct-to-zero-null

Comment: @Shepmaster: maybe `mem::zeroed()`?

Comment: @MatthieuM. I thought about that too, but it depends on the various values of the header allowing 0 (or equivalent) as a valid value. It's probably just better to go ahead and explicitly initialize each input field, reading the documentation to understand what everything needs to be set to. After that, maybe zeroing it out makes sense.